# How to create link to local index.html from Sphinx documentation?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm writing some docs for Sphinx/rst. How can I link to something on local disk which is relative to the page you're viewing?

For example:

```
====================
My App documentation
====================

The official My App documentation can be found here:
https://myapp.com/docs

A local mirror is available:
../../_static/docs_mirror/index.html
```

On my machine, the _static folder resides in:

```
file:///Users/fredrik/code/repos/myapp/docs/_static
```

...but I don't want to hard-code that path, as that path might not be the same path for another user who has downloaded cloned the repository.

Comment: @mzjn yes, excellent, that worked perfectly: `\`local mirror <_static/docs_mirror/index.html>\`_`. If you add an answer here I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
`local mirror <_static/docs_mirror/index.html>`_
```

Another option:

```
`local mirror`_

.. _local mirror: _static/docs_mirror/index.html
```

Reference: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-references.

Comment: This will only work if you're using this link in the root of the documentation. Elsewhere the `local mirror` will be inserted at the end of the current URL branch and resolve to an invalid page.